# Has there been any attempt to prevent false information from spreading? (legal fact check)

Tags: france, legislation, freedom-of-speech, fake-news

The French President, Emmanuel Macron, said during his new year press conference he would soon [propose laws preventing false information from spreading on the web](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/jan/03/emmanuel-macron-ban-fake-news-french-president) (*"fausses nouvelles"*, more or less equivalent to "fake news").

Has there been any attempts to do this in the past ?

Other than blasphemy trials of course (religious or not).

---

To clarify, the hard part would seem to me to be able to decree something to be false. It is quite hard to decide. Propaganda is usually build on either a selected set of true information, or unverifiable stories (plots mostly).

Let us say I see a documentary praising the liberation of Poland from communism by Nazi Germany. They can interview a few Polish people who say they are happy about it, stay vague, even say the economy is doing great. As long as they don't say any number, or false and verifiable fact, it cannot technically be counted as false.

Similarly, let us assume someone on TV speaks about a plot from globalist alien vampires to control the world. As long as I don't have a technique to vet if someone is an alien-vampire, I cannot consider it as false.

The only cases currently covered so far seem to be [defamation](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/defamation-law-made-simple-29718.html).

Comment: Different jurisdictions view libel and slander in different ways. For example courts in England & Wales tend to put the burden of proof on the person making the claim. This has in the past lead to court cases against non-UK publications happening the in the UK, because the publisher has exposure there.

Comment: It is difficult to say regarding different medias. As they are controlled by the french government, or by a handful of people, many things you read can turned into a "story" on purpose. Just remember the fake news from first french channel regarding the tchernobyl clouds over France that was stopped at the border https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGYKMXWq3js

Comment: Also, the whole french media, from TV to newspaper, is controlled by under 10 people. i guess it is worse than some other countries you can hear in the media nowadays....

Comment: @chickenburger A lot is controlled by around 10 people, not all of it. Some even refuse to include advertisement in order to keep their independence  (canard enchainé, médiapart, charlie hebdo, ...). But that is not the point. Rather if there has been any attempt of this kind to implement some kind of fact-checking into the law. Regardless of shareholders

Comment: @user5751924 i agree, but advertisement-free does not exclude them to follow an imposed breadcrumb narrative like other bigger companies. Which can confuse the reader if some newspaper use another newspaper as a source following the same narrative. Then fact-checking that looks legitimate to the average reader becomes suspicious to the one that is aware, thus questioning fact-check between news outlet that rely on each other (le monde, libération, le parisien, etc...)

Comment: Not to oultine that Macron's law preventing false information to spread to the internet is a blow to free speech and independant journalism. This is illegal and a great censorship. Especially if after his law, news outlet like Le Monde stays online continuing spreading news with only one rethoric as it has always done.

Comment: This would not be possible in this form under U.S. law, but most of the world and most of the Internet is subject to laws in addition to or different from U.S. law.

Comment: By "blasphemy" do you mean "libel".  Blasphemy is always religious.

Comment: France already has laws making denial of the Holocaust or the Armenian genocide illegal.

Comment: Note that Macron said that during an address to accredited journalists ("Voeux a la presse", that is New Year greetings to the press), mostly from traditional paper journals. Like most New Year resolutions, no one take them really seriously.

Comment: @chickenburger: "This is illegal and a great censorship". If the Parliament adopts the law and the Constitutional Council does not veto it, it will not be illegal. A great censorship for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laws against promoting false statements are already fairly common around the world, including in Europe, although more often exercised a [commercial or advertising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_advertising) context than in a [political](http://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/1993/0087/latest/whole.html#DLM310074) or purely journalistic one. Standards of evidence and the burden of proof on 'false statements' vary from "you can't describe your snake oil as 100% effective if every patient died" to "[you can't say your device cures cancer, even if it does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancer_Act_1939)", but within the context of a country's legal system the idea that some statements can be found true or untrue in court is certainly not new. Indeed, it's kind of the basis of the law.

The difficulty Macron appears to be attempting to address is that modern electronic communications makes it relatively cheap and easy to capture eyeballs, while maintaining anonymity. This makes restitution or punishment via exchange of money difficult, while a Presidential system makes the barrier to voiding and rerunning an election through court action rather high. Based on this coverage, his answer is to facilitate courts in forcing the swift removal of such material. Whether you consider this censorship and a restriction of free speech, an attempt to clean the Augean stables, or trying to put the toothpaste back into the tube will rather depend on your existing ideologies.

Answer (score 5):

One of the problems such efforts face is identifying what is false and what is true.

What is now popularly labeled 'fake news', and was once called propaganda, is almost never completely false. That would be too obvious. Typically, relevant facts or context are omitted to produce a false opinion on the part of the casual reader.

For example, let's consider the North Korean situation, specifically the artillery they have on the DMZ that they would presumably unleash on Seoul. This [Newsweek piece](http://www.newsweek.com/2017/05/05/what-war-north-korea-looks-588861.html) is pretty typical, in that it cites thousands of artillery cannon positioned by N Korea on the DMZ, capable of unleashing a devastation of Seoul, a highly populated city, very soon after hostilities open. Sounds like a catastrophe waiting to happen, right?

However, [this well researched article](http://nationalinterest.org/feature/north-korea-cant-destroy-seoul-artillery-23964) authored by two Indian military experts, one formerly in command of India's artillery, point out that ***none of N Korea's conventional artillery has the range to hit Seoul***, 40km from the DMZ. Only specialized cannon firing rocket assisted shells and MLRS launchers have that range, and N Korea has less than 1000 of them, which require rockets with a short shelf life. The impoverished N Korea would have to replace those rockets every couple of years to keep them effective.

Those rocket launchers will be able to get off one shot each, before the S Korean forces retaliate with great precision (radar will identify the launch points that aren't already known) and destroy the launch sites. It's not like the tech heavy S Korean military has been doing nothing in the face of this threat. (but the first article makes little mention of a S Korean retaliation... wouldn't generate the apprehension needed to keep you reading the story)

So, is the first story 'fake news'? Nowhere does it make absolutely false statements, it just omits relevant factors, such as range and the S Korean response. If you read it now after reading the second article, you'll find that the first one doesn't actually say that those 'thousands of artillery pieces' absolutely will hit Seoul, just that there are thousands of artillery pieces on the DMZ, and shells hitting Seoul would cause damage. It leaves you to fill in the gaps with your imagination. Clever, eh?

This same technique of selective omission and enhancement of existing fact is used in attempts to debunk global warming, and in attempts to exaggerate its effects, although identifying those omissions and enhancements is far more difficult than in this simple, obvious case.

The problem with legislating 'fake news' is identifying it. Who makes that determination? Is that group politically appointed, beholden to the political ideology of the people appointing them? In the end, such efforts amount to censorship, which has a number of drawbacks, even if it is said to be applied 'in the public good'. Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?

This is a case where the proposed solution may be worse than the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It would not be difficult, at all.

The problem is you are not separating reporting of and making statements of fact with statements of opinion. We're not talking about "I think your opinion is wrong" when talking about this kind of monitoring.

Macron is not targeting "I think Macron is stupid and his policies are idiotic," he's targeting "Macron eats babies and has sex with puppies, which is why he is evil."  A US example would be the one about Clinton and a business being linked to a child abduction and pornography ring. While, yes, that is pretty defamatory, the claim was that this was being run in the basement of the pizza restaurant. That business's building did not have a basement level. And yet that "story" was spread very widely, and even by high-level government and campaign officials.

The first clause of the second statement is presented as fact, and can easily be demonstrated to be true or false. Or, at the very least if it's a case of "you can't prove the negative," it can be determined, quite easily, that the person making that claim has met or has not met an objective standard of evidence before offering that claim.

Obviously, there would be a lot of discussion over where the burden of proof lies (you have to have proof before making a claim vs you have to be able to disprove to sanction for a claim), and I think it would differ depending on the kind of statements being made, but the idea that facts are fungible and impossible to determine is a concept that, basically, people who find actual facts inconvenient for their agenda like to claim, but has no logical basis.

Note that my statement that it would not be difficult to create a standard is not necessarily an endorsement of the concept, just refuting the idea that the truth of facts is somehow impossible to determine.

One example of trying to enforce standards of reliability or honesty, and not just having an excuse to crush any critical or dissenting opinions is Canada's Radio Act. While not all-encompassing, it does apply certain standards:

It is against the law for any organization that is licensed as a broadcaster to broadcast false or misleading news. This was actually, originally, in Canada's criminal code and was used to prosecute a Holocaust denier, Ernst Zündel, in the early 1980s, but the Canadian Supreme Court ruled that it was too much of an infringement on free expression rights. The ruling was that these requirements were to be used as regulations, instead.

[Is Fox News banned in Canada? | PunditFact - PolitiFact](http://www.politifact.com/punditfact/statements/2014/jul/14/facebook-posts/fox-news-banned-canada/)

(Note, the reason I referenced the above link is because it contained the passage where they describe the previous law and use against the Holocaust denier).

The previous Prime Minister in Canada wanted to get rid of these regulatory requirements, completely, in 2011 but that initiative was rejected and the regulations stand.

[CRTC ditches bid to allow fake news - The Globe and Mail](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/politics/ottawa-notebook/crtc-ditches-bid-to-allow-fake-news/article1921489/)

Comment: "Macron eats babies and has sex with puppies, which is why he is evil" can already be condemned as defamation, if Macron decides to go to court. I think he already went for some fake news about a hidden offshore account (I think it is mentionned in a link to the answer). The limit seems hard to place when it comes to plots for instance. Or misquoted studies (typically, catchy vague headtitle: "X% of group Y support isis/hitler/stalin/... " while the poll is not that clear)

Comment: I noticed you got a -1 right away, before I finished reading. I don't know where that came from.

Comment: @user5751924 - I was demonstrating more that it was a statement of fact. I could very well have used "Macron has the smallest hands of any world leader" or something non-defamatory (well, Trump considers it defamatory by implication, but he's a bit insecure). The -1 probably came from someone who finds facts inconvenient and likes to argue that they can't ever be determined. Or they just disagree and don't feel I made a valid argument.

Comment: @user5751924 An important distinction would be between attempting to collect damages (i.e monetary compensation) versus an injunction to stop making statement a court has determined to be false/unprovable. In the context of an election, particularly with a short European style campaign, the second is a lot more important than the first.

Comment: @origimbo - I agree. This is why I'm not overly concerned about whether there is overlap with something that might be covered by a civil defamation action. Individual, personal tort vs. societal/government sanction.

Comment: Sure, creating a Ministry of Truth is not really all that technically challenging, but I think the question is history based; "Has there been any attempts to do this in the past?" which I don't think this answer addresses.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt - right you are.  I'll make some edits to answer more fully.

Comment: I think one problem shows up when false/misleading claims are reported with sufficient couching language to release liability of whether a given fact is true or not, e.g. "Some are saying that Macron eats babies and has his way with puppies". The fact that some are saying could itself be true, whether or not the underlying statement is true. It is a true fact that Clinton _allegedly_ ran a sex ring out of a pizza shop, because some people were alleging it. The true fact that she wasn't doesn't have much bearing on that, and that's why laws prohibiting what you can/cannot say are hard.

Comment: I think it might be overly simplistic to say that it's easy to determine truth, especially when political interests come into play(There are still people who defend Clinton's "I didn't have sexual relations with that woman" as some variety of truth).  Might even go so far as to suggest it is incredibly dangerous for democracies to even distantly court the idea of a ministry of truth, at least until we perfect a cold emotionless AI that holds truth /very/ high above feelings or any other number of reasons that truth might get twisted into 'fake news'.

Comment: @JeffLambert That concept is what lead the UK to the "super-injunction" which prevented media discussion of existing court proceedings, at least theoretically to protect the privacy and reputation of the litigants, with the usual threats and penalties if not adhered to. This makes the laws also a) weird and b) expensive.

Comment: There are very few "facts" in hot topics of discussion (economics, sociology, criminology etc pp), as they are not hard sciences. If the "facts" change every few years, I recon it will be quite difficult to turn this into something that isn't "this statement doesn't align with the current government's opinion, and is therefore illegal".

Comment: @janh: there are lots of "facts" in those topics if you care to look. See e.g. Steve Keen's Debunking Economics, which ruthlessly debunks economic "facts" with actual (empirical) facts. And there are plenty of (experimental) social psychology books that give you plenty of basis to cover - and indeed debunk or reinterpret - "facts" in sociology, criminology, etc.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy That's what I meant. What economists agree on as factual changes quite often, and quite heavily depending on which economists you ask. To have judges decide what is true (and is therefore allowed to be said) on a science that often looks like a religion is problematic at best.

Comment: @janh: I think you're misreading my comment. What I'm saying is that economists on all sides of the spectrum are living like ostriches with their hands buried in the sand, while blissfully ignoring proper facts - and Keen does a wonderful job raising the latter as he debunks what they think. The facts are there. It's just that academia has yet to catch up. Likewise for sociology and other social sciences: there are systematically reproducible _facts_ that, whatever one's opinion on this or that connected topic, are utterly not rejectable.

Comment: @JackOfAllTrades234 - re: people defending Clinton. They may argue about how one might characterize that, but the facts of the matter - that he received/exchanged oral sexual acts with Lewinsky, are very easy to confirm as fact.  So, no, that's not a good example. I'm talking about the latter - actual statements of fact, not the former - spinning and characterizing the facts for advantage.

Answer (score -5):

How about something that is not connected to politics or personality, like the "vaccines cause autism" garbage, or - to pick something both current and as neutral as possible - the nonsense about a "blue moon" being the second full moon in a month.

Blue moons are a real, though rare (thus the expression "once in a blue moon") phenomenon caused by localized atmosphic conditions, yet every time a month happens to have two full moons, we're bombarded with the false definition of a blue moon.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. I don't really see the relevance of "blue moons" (which I thought meant the third full moon out of 4 in a season with four full moons)

Comment: Is this an attempt to clarify a case where such censorship is desirable or practical? That doesn't seem to be what this question calls for, and the examples cited don't seem very good for it. Anti-vax has conspiracy theory threads, (suppressing a conspiracy theory is lunacy) and your moon story is at least 50 years too late to stop the spread of the month based version, and the season one is older than that, at some point language moves on irregardless (sigh) of origins or logic.

Comment: @James K: See, you've already been corrupted by false information :-)  It wasn't meant as an ANSWER, because AFAIK there IS no answer to the problem of false information being spread, despite the best efforts of Snopes, FactCheck.org, and others.  If you, or anyone, can find better examples, or even an instance where a false-but-attractive story was stopped, I'd be glad to see it.